# Java Client/Ruby Server Socket connection

Tags: java, android, ruby, sockets

I was recently asked to do an android app for the company i work on. My experience is mostly on Ruby/C++/C#, so programming on Java (though sintax its familiar) its a new thing to me.

I have this method on my client (Java) that basically set ups a connection to the Ruby server via socket. It works fine when it comes to sending text to the server. Here's code for both the server and the client.

Client (JAVA)

```
public static void call_socket(String[] cadena)
    {
        PrintWriter salida;
        DataInputStream entrada;

        try 
        {    
            if(SocketClass.sockethost == "")
            {
                if(SocketClass.socketport == 0)
                {
                    get_instalacion();
                }
            }
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
            clientSocket.bind(null);
            clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SocketClass.sockethost, SocketClass.socketport),30000);
            salida = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);         
            salida.println(Arrays.toString(cadena)); 
           } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
            return;
        }   

};
```

Server (RUBY)

```
require 'socket'
require 'pg'
require 'openssl'
server = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0',3000)
loop do
    Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        chain= client.gets
        chain= chain.delete('[')
        chain  = chain.delete(']')
        chain = chain.gsub(/\s+/, "")
        chain = chain.gsub(',', "|")
        arr_cade = chain.split("|")
        pg_conn = PGconn.connect(:host=> 'localhost', :dbname => 'termventas', :port => 5432, :user => 'postgres', :password=> 'pass')
        case arr_cade[1]
            when "01"
                arr_cade[2] = arr_cade[2].gsub(/\s+/, "")
                arr_cade[2]= arr_cade[2].upcase
                arr_cade[3] = arr_cade[3].upcase
                result = pg_conn.exec("SELECT entrada, clave_venta FROM terminales_usuarios 
                                       WHERE entrada = '#{arr_cade[2]}' 
                                       AND clave_venta = '#{arr_cade[3]}'")
                if result.count == 0 || result == nil
                    puts "Empty"
                else
                    client.puts "Welcome"                   
                end
        end
        pg_conn.PGconn.close()
        client.close
    end
end
```

Now, as I said, everything works fine when it comes to sending a request to the server, im able to send the correct string[] and properly evaluate it at the socket server. Now im trying to implement getting input FROM the server at the client. I've done some research and this is basically what i've found that needs to be done in order to capture the input produced by the server:

```
        BufferedReader server_input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String answer_back= server_input.readLine();
        Log.v("Response", answer_back);
```

However if i do it like that it prompts me to either add a throw declaration or surround it with try/catch. I proceed to add the try/catch and compile my code.

What happens next after i execute the action that triggers the socket connection it hangs. The application doesnt crash or anything, the socket simply dont respond (neither sending/receiving). I really dont know what's causing this. If i remove the sentences that involve capturing and displaying the string returned by the server, everything works fine.

Any idea?

BTW, im using Eclipse and also using the emulator to, well, emulate my android device.

Comment: i dont know if this will work. try ``client.close_write`` after writing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured where my problem was at. It wasnt at my client (Java) but at my server (Ruby). When i do the SQL query to figure out if theres a use registered with the data sent through the socket, when there was not registries found, i wasnt sending any response back to the client. See as i had this line:

```
puts "Empty"
```

Which was literally just printing the result in my server log. By changing the respond to actually be delivered to the client, i just did this:

```
client.puts "Empty"
```

Therefore, my java client had a response from the server both times (when the sql query returned something or not) and it doesn't hang up anymore, which i assume was caused by the client "listening" and expecting a replied from the server, but never really getting any at all (unless the sql query returned something other than nil).

Hope this is useful for anyone in the future. Thanks to everyone who took some time to review/replied to my message.